# What's the vertical line in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, there is a vertical line as highlighted on the screenshot.

When I copy a long line of code into the editor, it wraps automatically if longer than this line.

[image: screenshot]

What is this line and what's its purpose?

Comment: It's showing the line break that you specified in settings (e.g. 80 or 120 characters).

Comment: In your editor settings you can define line length... if you outformated the code, it would take this as reference... its most likely set based on PEP standard...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That’s the wrap guide. It is a visual indicator of when your lines of code are getting too long. It defaults to the column that your Preferred Line Length is set to.

To deactivate the line:

Settings->Editor->Appearance then deselect "Show right margin".

Comment: Its `Settings->Editor->General->Appearance` in PyCharm 2020.1

Answer (score 48):

It is a guide for the "hard wrap" setting.

Setting screenshots from IntelliJ IDEA (PyCharm should be similar):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's called a visual guide (Settings - Editor - Code Style). It helps you to see how wide is each line of code, and to keep the lines within this limit. You can configure the IDE to wrap the lines automatically when the lines are too long.

As [stated in pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), in Python lines should be no longer than 79 chars, and some of them should be 72 at most. So it might be a good idea to have 2 visual guides: at 72 and 79 columns.

Answer (score 1):

It has been few years since the last answers were relevant.
In newer versions of Pycharm go to:

`Settings->Editor->General->Appearance`

Then, unmark `Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)` (as highlighted in the picture):

[image]